# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql

Вылезает вот такая ошибка

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

```
// СОСЧИТАТЬ ВСЕХ НЕАКТИВИРОВАННЫХ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕЙ
function users_total($index = false, $where = false, $order = false){
global $mysqli, $num_rows;

if(!$where){
    $where = " WHERE id <> '' ";
}

if(!$order){
    $order = " id DESC ";
}

if($index){
    $where .= " AND views_in = 'y' AND big <> ''";
}

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users $where ORDER BY $order ";
//print $sql;
$users_query = $mysqli->query($sql);

//if($users_total){
$users_total = $num_rows($users_query);
//}
return $users_total;

}
```

Вот тут ошибка

```
//if($users_total){
$users_total = $num_rows($users_query);
//}
return $users_total;
```

Моя закомментированная проверка не помогает кто знает как решить?

Comment: Надо раскомментировать print $sql, посмотреть на получившееся чудо и исправить код

Comment: потом выкинуть бессмысленные части запроса (сортировка при подсчете не нужна и id никогда не бывает равно пустой строке) и [поменять запрос так чтобы он запрашивал сразу количество](https://phpize.online/?phpses=015e54cbd0c715192139e057582f96a3&sqlses=5f9de9607f152aca175728b9c989ad7a&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Вывод sql такой: SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users WHERE id <> '' AND views_in = 'y' AND big <> '' ORDER BY id DESC на страничке отображены активированные пользователи поэтому неактивированные пустые вот и появляется ошибка, потому что проверки нет, нужно как-то проверить, я попробовал вашу идею, но безуспешно